# Can we decompile an .exe or .dll as %100?

Tags: decompilation, decompile, decompiler, c#

1. Can we decompile a .exe or .dll file as **100%**? Also sometimes seems some
   mistakes on somewhere (like mainfrm.cs) , how can we fix that?
2. What is the best **.NET decompiler**? or What would you prefer?

I wanna get an  answer for my questions. Thanks!...

Comment: Decompilation is not something you can easily perform programmatically, some tools try but eventually you'll have to have a human do at least some of the work.

Comment: Could you be more clear? so when i decompiled a file it was giving  like 140+ errors, couldn't fix it...

Answer (score 3):

Since the compilation output of .NET languages is [MSIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), which is quite readable itself, it can be transformed back to (almost) original source code.
There are many applications which can do that.
My favourite is [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy) since it's free, open source and has debugging functionalities. AFAIK it can even try to build a Visual Studio Solution (`.sln`) file from your input which should be what you look for.

**But** under certain circumstances some information is lost during the compilation process.
You would have to manually fix those errors. For example anonymous functions can confuse a decompiler easily. And of course - if the developer tries to protect his application there are various techniques like obfuscation which would make your life harder.

**So to answer your questions directly:**

1. In most cases there isn't a 100% `Plug and Play` solution. You will have to fix a few things yourself if you want to have a recompilable project.
2. Since `best ..` is very subjective here are a few suggestions (in no particular order):

   1. https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy (free, open source)
   2. https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/ (paid)
   3. https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/ (free?)
   4. http://ilspy.net/ (free, open source)